# Criar banco de dados e superusuarios automaticamente com Django

Tags: python-3.x, django-2.0

Desenvolvi um sistema com `Python` e `Django`. Agora eu gostaria de disponibilizá-lo na web para que usuários possam criar contas no sistema, para isso seria necessário que cada usuário tenha o seu banco de dados.

Hoje, para criar o meu usuário eu utilizo o comando `python manage.py createsuperuser` e no arquivo `settings.py` especifico o banco de dados que quero utilizar.

Hospedei o meu app em um servidor no `DigitalOcean` e lá configurei o sistema como fiz localmente, mas agora, como faço para automatizar a criação de novos usuários e que para cada um gere o seu respectivo banco?

Answer (score 0):

No caso sua aplicação deve ter uma implementação para dar aos usuários que são cadastrados, permissão de superusuario. Recomendo dar uma lida na documentação do Django na parte de criação de usuários.  Creio eu que não é necessário um banco para cada usuário, pois todos usuário seram cadastrados e registrados em um único banco, onde sua aplicação vai realizar consultas e escrita.
De uma lida nesta documentação que possa clariar suas ideias para implementar. [Django Auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/)

Comment: Meu sistema é de gerenciamento de produtos, ou seja, cada usuário vai ter seus produtos, seus clientes, suas vendas, e assim por diante. Para todos os usuários as tabelas serão as mesmas, assim é essencial cada usuário ter o seu banco